# Error when forward declaring a struct: "has a previous declaration here"

Tags: c++

When building my small C++ project, I get the following 2 errors, can't figure out the cause:

- error: using typedef-name 'TTF_Font' after 'struct'.
  Points to the following line of code: `struct TTF_Font;` in Foo.h.
- error: 'TTF_Font' has a previous declaration here.
  Points to the following line of code: `typedef struct _TTF_Font TTF_Font;` in SDL_ttf.h.

I've narrowed it down to the following files in a new test project:

Foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

struct TTF_Font;

class Foo
{
    TTF_Font* font;
};

#endif // FOO_H
```

Foo.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"

// No implementation, just testing
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    Foo a;
    return 0;
}
```

Do you guys know what I'm doing wrong?

My goal is to forward declare TTF_Font, so I can use it in my header file without including the SDL_ttf header file. I read that including header files in other header files was kinda bad practice, so I switched to forward declarations. All my other forward declarations work fine except this single struct.

When I replace the forward declaration `struct TTF_Font;` with the header include `#include "SDL/SDL.ttf.h"`, it compiles without errors. So I can use that, but I want to know WHY, dammit :-).

Extra info: I'm using the Code::Blocks IDE with mingw32 compiler. Project uses the SDL graphics library. Not much C++ experience yet, come from C# background.

Comment: Are you sure your code snippet for `Foo.cpp` is correct?  The error message is implying that the stuff in `Foo.h` is occurring *after* the inclusion of `SDL_ttf.h`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to forward declare something as a different type to what it actually is.

You are declaring:

```
struct TTF_Font;
```

when the error message indicates that `TTF_Font` is actually a `typedef`, not a `struct`:

```
typedef struct _TTF_Font TTF_Font;
```

The stuct is actually called `_TTF_Font`.

You can declare the same `typedef` multiple times so you can just use the `typedef` declaration instead of the forward declaration to declare the `struct` and introduce the `typedef` although it does feel a bit like you are using implementation details of the header that you are trying to defer including.

Comment: Thanks! When I use the same typedef line from the header file it works, but like you already mention it's kinda using the details of the SDL_ttf header file. Is there a best practice for this kind of thing? Should I just leave out the forward declaration and simply include the header file in cases like this?

Comment: @void_Foo: Generally, including the header file is the safest option. If there's an acceptable way to forward declare something from a library or a "declarations only" header file then the library documentation should indicate this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in this code snippet:

```
struct foo_t;

typedef struct foo { ... } foo_t;
```

The first line is a forward-declaration of a *different* struct, whose name clashes with the `typedef`.  The forward declaration in this case needs to be `struct foo;`, because the name of the `struct` itself is `foo`.